# Is there an alternative to "Arnold" for Houdini Apprentice?

Tags: particles, particle-system, houdini

I've been working in Houdini Apprentice, trying to learn about FLIP tanks, but the tutorial I'm using explains the shader texturing of particles by using "Arnold shader network". As I looked further into it, I saw that Arnold is not included in Houdini Apprentice. Is there an alternative to particle shaders for Houdini that I could look in to?

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to use **Mantra** or **Karma** (depending on your Houdini version) as Houdini Apprentice doesn't allow any 3rd party renderer (such as Arnold).

Here's the difference between the different Houdini licences:
https://www.sidefx.com/products/compare/